# NetLogo - How to show the current coordinates of a turtle

Tags: netlogo

I have been trying for quite some time to show the current coordinates of a turtle in NetLogo. I'm aware that to show one of the coordinates, I could use:

```
show [xcor] of turtle 0
```

or

```
show [ycor] of turtle 0
```

But how do I show both coordinates?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `show [list xcor ycor] of turtle 0`.

Or, fancier: `show [(word "(" xcor ", " ycor ")")] of turtle 0`.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't know the exact turtle (`of turtle 5`) who's coordinates you would like to show but you want to identify the position of specific turtle running a process you can use just

```
show list xcor ycor  ; not need to use self or myself
```

Comment: this can be simplified to just `show list xcor ycor`. it never adds meaning to use `of self`

Comment: Thank you @SethTisue, I have modified it in my code :)

Answer (score -4):

From
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#syntax

you can do

show [xcor + ycor] of turtle 5

But not sure if that helps?

sorry.. it doesnt.. 1 sec!

Comment: yup dude, it doesnt. Tried that out too! haha! What I want is both the coordinates, that adds them up

Comment: yep.. I know I misread your Q!
Not sure if you can in 1 statement?

Comment: i think there is just enquired from a frd earlier. Could do with patch-here. ask turtle [ patch-here ] it returns the coordinates xy

Comment: @aHaH: if the turtle is on a patch center, then its coordinates are integers, and the same as the coordinates of the patch. but if the turtle isn't on the patch center, then its coordinates are different